# Search View in Toolbar Android Null pointer Exception [ SearchView searchView = (SearchView) getActionView(searchItem); ]

Tags: android

**Error**
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.View android.view.MenuItem.getActionView()' on a null object reference at MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu

the code for search view on the toolbar

Java

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) getActionView(searchItem);
    ComponentName componentName = new 
    ComponentName(context,MainActivity.class); 
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName));}
```

Menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="Search" />
```

XML

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />
```

Comment: Try `MenuItemCompat` hope that fix your issue. `SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);`

Answer (score 0):

- Add this lines to the ProGuard file

  ```
  -keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
  -keep interface android.support.** { *; }
  ```
- Replace this line `SearchView searchView = (SearchView) getActionView(searchItem);` with

  ```
  SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
  ```
- `Theme.AppCompat` instead of `Theme.Base.AppCompat`

Check above steps and feedback if that helped you to fix your issue.